# insert record to a new worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

Currently I have a weekly report workbook and import export workbook.

In Weekly report, I have 3 worksheet iron ore, steel scrap and wire rod.

Every time user enter these fields in any of the 3 work sheet in weekly report

```
Index   Contract no Seller  Bank    Buyer   Issuing Bank    Product Vessel
```

I need to reflect it in import export workbook.

Is it possible?

[image: Sample of my excel sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe?

```
=IF([Weekly_report.xls]Sheet1!A2="";"";[Weekly_report.xls]Sheet1!A2)
```